# Append timestamp to powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to capture some data on CPU activity on a SQL instance.

Get-Process | Sort CPU -descending | Select -first 10 -Property ID,ProcessName,CPU

The PowerShell above give me the following output :

[image]

How do i modify the powershell to include a timestamp for each row. And output should look something like this.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a calculated property to you output like this

```
Get-Process | Sort CPU -descending | Select -first 10 @{l="Time";e={get-date}},ID,ProcessName,CPU
```

The syntax for adding a calculated property is

```
 @{                  - start a script block
   l = 'label';      - choose a label for the property (not mandatory)
   e = {expression}  - formulate the expression you like evaluated
 }                   - close the script block
```